# Fetch API handle error 407 is not same between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, web, fetch, http-status-code-407

When I call API and it returns error 407, I would like to handle this case but I very surprised when I found that response from Chrome and Firefox is not the same.

```
fetch('https://xxxx.xxx/xxx', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  },
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('res', response)
}, function(error) {
  console.log('err', error)
})
```

[Result in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYg82.png)

[Result in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJMCP.png)

Chrome goes to error case, nothing to tell me about this 407 error, but Firefox can get status code.

I don't know it a bug or my fault, I already Google but I nothing to make me clear. Please help me clear on this issue, Thanks.

Comment: which browser do you consider is correct?

Comment: @JaromandaX I prefer Firefox because it have data response from server

Comment: Hello,
having the same issue. How do you handle 407 in Chrome the same way as Firefox does ?

Comment: @Franck I'm not, so I fixed it by change error code from 407 to 403

Comment: The same for me. I went back to 401 with a custom response header.